# How do I avoid a template get rendered from a preprocess function?

Tags: theming, 8

I have a multilingual site with two view blocks, and a custom template for them.

I want to render both blocks in language A, but only one in language B.
Is it possible to avoid that one of them is rendered on a language basis, from the preprocess function?

Answer (score 5):

Why preprocess?

Blocks have language visibility. Just configure that block to be shown only in a specific language.

Comment: thanks for the answer. So in preprocess it is not possible.

Comment: @MudassarAli It is possible but why to bother that if there is existing solution? Or any reason that you don't want to make it in this way?

Answer (score 1):

To anyone coming here from a search:

As Berdir says, for the problem described in the question we don't need to use preprocess.

However, if you need this for some other reason, the following hack does the trick, for whichever theme hook you want to target:

```php
function mymodule_preprocess_HOOK(array &$variables, string $hook, array &$info): void {
  if (...) {
    $info['function'] = '';
  }
}
```

The `$info` array is a local variable in `ThemeManager::render()` that is loaded from the theme registry, and then passed to preprocess functions in a way that supports treating it as a by-reference parameter.

Setting `$info['function']` overrides any template that would otherwise be rendered. If we use a function name that does not exist, we get an empty string as output.

In `\Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager::render()`:

```php
    // Generate the output using either a function or a template.
    $output = '';
    if (isset($info['function'])) {
      if (function_exists($info['function'])) {
        // Theme functions do not render via the theme engine, so the output is
        // not autoescaped. However, we can only presume that the theme function
        // has been written correctly and that the markup is safe.
        $output = Markup::create($info['function']($variables));
      }
    }
    else {
      $render_function = 'twig_render_template';
```

Disclaimer: You need to determine case by case whether doing this in preprocess is the correct solution. This answer only describes a technical possibility.

Comment: Which `HOOK` in `mymodule_preprocess_HOOK`?

Comment: @leymannx For whichever theme hook you want to target. This is a generic answer that addresses the title of the question. The more specific question is better solved by setting the block visibility condition as suggested by Berdir. Also it seems the question author already had a specific preprocess function in mind.

Comment: We are currently using this trick with hook_preprocess_field(), hook_preprocess_layout() and hook_preprocess_paragraph(), to prevent rendering of empty wrappers.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. 

Comment: This supposed to be removed in Drupal 10 - @see \Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry::processExtension() `Theme functions are deprecated in drupal:8.0.0 and are removed from drupal:10.0.0. Use Twig templates instead of %s(). See https://www.drupal.org/node/1831138` - Is there a workaround for themes that can't add a callback to `#pre_render` array to set `#printed = TRUE` and use `hook_block_access()` etc. ?

Comment: FYI this trick doesn't work anymore since Drupal 9.4 because of these 2 changes:
https://www.drupal.org/i/2760659
https://www.drupal.org/i/3097889

Comment: @HervéDonner I see the check was replaced with `is_callable()`. Shouldn't this have the same effect for empty string?

Comment: @donquixote The problem is the next line, which now calls call_user_func_array(). This prevents passing the $info var as reference and modifying it.
The other issue (added to drupal 10.1.x) is even more problematic since it removed theme functions and the code highlighted in this answer.

Comment: FYI I created https://www.drupal.org/i/3380299 to try and figure out a way to resolve this.

Comment: My bad, you are completely right! My comment would only make sense if this check was for the theme function, but not for the preprocess function.

Answer (score 0):

+1 from me for the answer from @Berdir.

If you really need to do this in preprocess, this depends, for which template the preprocess is:

In page you can remove a block from a region:

```
unset($variables['page']['myregion']['mytheme_myblock']);
```

In block template you can remove the content and if necessary the label to prevent any further rendering.

```
$variables['content'] = [];
$variables['label'] = [];
```

There should be similar solutions at any point in preprocess.

Answer (score 0):

If the blocks are in a view, you can use `Hide block if the view output is empty' = Yes` & then set `$view->result = [];` in `hook_views_post_render()`.

You can use nest other blocks in the views header to get this ability for the inner block too.

Example & detailed code:

[Hide a view programatically D8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253317/hide-a-view-programatically-d8/305839#305839)